# Property of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a positive definite matrix $P.$ How do I prove that $$\inf_{\|x\|_2 = 1}\|Px\|_2 = \inf_{\|x\|_2 = 1} x^TPx$$

Comment: might be that you can modify the proof found here to match your inf-case: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840141/dual-norm-equivalence

Comment: $||Px||_2=\sqrt{x^TP^TPx}$, then use the eigen-decomposition of $P$ and simplify.

Comment: Wouldn't the eigendecomposition simplify to $\sqrt{x^TU\Lambda^2U^Tx}$?, how would I make the next step?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\inf_{\|x\|_2 = 1} x^TP^2x = \lambda_{min}^2\\
\inf_{\|x\|_2 = 1} x^TPx = \lambda_{min}
$$
This fact is sometimes referred to as "Rayleigh's theorem".  However, it is simple enough to prove directly; in particular, it suffices to show that this holds when $P$ is diagonal.